# Comparing and insert/update/delete children in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, linq

I have a multiple selection form that needs to be saved into the database. Users can edit their selections on their subsequent visits. The items are defined in a table with unique IDs so the form only pass back a list of IDs.

It is something like:

```
Fruits:
    { id=1, name="apple" }
    { id=2, name="orange" }
    { id=3, name="banana" }

People:
    { id=1, name="user", fruits=apple,orange }
```

In DB there is a link table linking the id of people and id of fruits.

Now when I receive a request to edit, I'll need to compare with existing fruits so I know whether I need to add or delete an entry.

```
foreach (var fruit in existing_fruits)
{
    if (post_fruits.Where(e => e.id == fruit.id).Count() == 0) user.Fruits.Remove(fruit);
}

foreach (var fruit in post_fruits)
{
    if (existing_fruits.Where(e => e.id == fruit.id).Count() == 0)
    {
        var entity = context.Fruit.Where(e => e.id == fruit.id);
        user.Fruits.Add(entity);
    }
}
```

As you can see there are multiple loops and multiple which call on the lists, which makes me wonder if there is a cleaner way in doing this?

Comment: It's boilerplate but a standing candidate for a highly reusable helper function. I'd also remove query repeated two times, one to count and one to search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What if you use .Any method here (although it still uses two loops but it is more efficient) :

```
foreach (var fruit in existing_fruits)
    if (!post_fruits.Any(e => e.id == fruit.id)) user.Fruits.Remove(fruit);

foreach (var fruit in post_fruits)
{
    if (existing_fruits.Any(e => e.id == fruit.id)) continue;
    var entity = context.FirstOrDefault(e => e.id == fruit.id);
    if(entity != null) user.Fruits.Add(entity);
}
```

But it's better to change DB architecture to:

```
Fruits:
    { id=1, name="apple" }
    { id=2, name="orange" }
    { id=3, name="banana" }

People:
    { id=1, name="user" }

PeopleFruits
    { id=1, fruitId = 1, personId = 1, isSelected = 0}
```

All you need to update records now is to get this PeopleFruits entities of some person.

```
PeopleFruits[] personPplFruits = cont.PeopleFruits.Where(pf => pf.personId == 1).ToArray();
```

And update `.isSelected` properties according to what user has selected.

Check this article please : https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/how-to-get-database-design-horribly-wrong/

Comment: Thanks for the `Any` suggestion, I'll use that. For the DB architecture, do you mean I need to build an exhaustive list of fruit x person combination? It can grow pretty quick.

Comment: That is correct but it's better from architectural point of view to avoid storing multiple values inside a plain string... (it is a bad design for testing and using)...

Comment: Oh it's a misunderstanding. In my case I'm using a link table (peopleId, fruitId), but I'll add and delete records in this link table instead of creating all and set a flag for them.

Comment: @lcycool Not sure what is better here. When i faced a similar problem, I thought that i'd better add extra entries to my database once and then only work with corresponding entries that are linked with userID. In this scenario i can simply change bool IsChecked property than to constantly re-create entries when user unchecked all checkboxes (deselecting items) and then selected them all back again. If you really need to work with vast amount of entries it's better to use noSQL databases.

Answer (score 3):

There are a lot of useful functions in [EntityFramework.Extended](https://github.com/loresoft/EntityFramework.Extended). It contains **Batch Update and Delete** feature which can be useful in your situation, it also eliminates the need to retrieve and load an entity before modifying it, so it can increase your performance in future.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But for now we are not considering adding plugin to the existing system =)